# How to get out of browser to work on a silverlight application?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I have a silverlight application and i have already checked the box that enables OOB. When i run the program from the IDE and i right click on the browser, i do not get an option to install the application. Instead i have an option to remove the application.

I would like to get an icon that other users can just click on in order to run the application. Is there a reason why i do not have the option to install the application when i run my program?

If it matters i am using silverlight 5.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have the option to remove the application means you have installed out of browser in the past, after clicking "remove the application" you will have the option to install the application locally.

Comment: I tried this, but when i click "remove the application" and i run the program again i - once again - do not have the option to install the application locally

Comment: beneath the "enable OOB" checkbox there is out-of-broswer settings button, click it to bring the settings window, make sure you have "show install menu" checked